# multivalued lookup field reading as duplicates

Tags: ms-access

I have a form entitled "training sessions" in the form is a multi-value lookup field where I can tick off the names of people who attended that session. It works fine except where two people have the same last name. When I try to click two people with the same last name, I get the error "you cannot enter that value because it duplicates an existing value in the multi-valued lookup or attachment field."

Again, the last names are the same but the first names are different. Is there something I can do to keep it from reading as a duplicate?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you share the source of that Multivalued field? How did youi set it up - where will the result be stored? What result? In asking questions: always think of the one qho wants to help: do give all informations that could help the helper to help you ;)

Comment: Use a unique identifier for each person and save that as foreign key. An autonumber field could serve that purpose. Advise not to use multi-value fields anyway.

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to make sure I included the key column in the query and it understands now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to make sure the key was included in my query.